# How to make location mandatory to use the app

Tags: react-native

I want the app user to turn on their location when the app is using. From the app startup to end.

Currently I'm checking the location on the app startup in App.js file. But it is not checking the location on each an every screen on the app.

```
const [currentLocation, setCurrentLocation] = useState({
    latitude: null,
    longitude: null,
});

useEffect(() => {
    const grantLocationAccess = async () => {
        const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
            PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
            {
                'title': 'App Location Permission',
                'message': 'App App needs access to your location ',
            }
        );

        setLocationAccessGranted(granted);

        if (granted) {
            Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
                (position) => {
                    console.log("My current location", JSON.stringify(position));
                    setCurrentLocation({
                        latitude: position.coords.latitude.toString(),
                        longitude: position.coords.longitude.toString(),
                    });
                },
                (error) => {
                    console.log(error.code, error.message);
                },
                { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 15000, maximumAge: 10000 }
            );
        }
    };

    grantLocationAccess();
}, []);
```

What can I do to make the location mandatory on the app life time.

Comment: It's a bad idea to regularly use location services because location services are heavy on battery consumption. If you continuously check user's location on each screen, your app will drain their battery a lot more and you'll have negative reviews on play store and app store. Instead, you can use a setTimeout func that checks user's location at regular intervals. 1 min or more. A more sophisticated approach will be to check a few times and use that to calculate how much the user's moving around. If not a lot, you needn't keep checking their location. Again all of this depends on your usecase.

Comment: @TomBombadil thanks for the suggestion. I'm tracking location once a 15 minute. But to get the location the user needs to keep turn on their location. So that's why I asked this question.

Comment: @mxmissile This is app for our employees. It will be not be available for public. We're tracking their location in case of emergency once a 15 minute time :)

Comment: Are your employees ok with you tracking them? Sounds really fishy to me! More like you want to track them and not for emergencies. Because if it's for emergencies why will the employee choose to turn off their location services voluntarily? Knowing it can help them out of the problem they are in? Also, why would you want such a check in all screens if it is in case of emergencies? The employee is going through an emergency, has the time to use the app but not call you directly? Why wouldn't they just call you instead and share their location via chat? WhatsApp or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is HOC for permission checks, You can wrap your entire App inside this one, You can check geolocation in `GeoLocationWrapper`  Component and If it's not granted You can ask for permission again.

```
<GeoLocationWrapper>
   <App/>
</GeoLocationWrapper>
```